# How can I get this code using an array to run correctly?

Tags: c

So I am trying to fix this code. When I run the compiler it runs but the results populate as zero's instead of correct dollar amounts. What am I missing here?

```
// Array Discussion Code
// Sales Tax Calculator
int main() 
{
    //main function initialization
    int x, num; //initialization of integer values
    float array[10], total, tax;//initialization of array, total, and tax floats

    printf("Enter the sales tax rate in your state (in 0.xx format): ");//user is prompted to enter their state sales tax rate
    scanf("%f", &tax);//user enters their sales tax rate
    printf("\nEnter the number of items you purchased: ");//prompts the user for the number of items they bought
    scanf("%d", &num);//user inputs the number of products they bought
    printf("\nEnter the price of each item: ");//prompts the user to begin entering the prices of each item

    for (x = 0; x<num; x++){//for loop to allow user to input the number of values they want
        scanf("%f", &array[num]);//user inputs a value
        total = 0;//initial value of total
    }
    for (x = 0; x < num; x++){//loop executes as many times as there are items
        total = total + array[x];//for loop to find the total of all items

        printf("\nYour total before tax is $%.2f", total); //program displays total before tax

        tax = tax * total;//total sales tax is calculated

        printf("\nYour sales tax is $%.2f", tax);//total sales tax is displayed

        total = tax + total;//grand total is calculated

        printf("\nYour grand total is $%.2f", total);//grand total is displayed
    }
    return 0;
}//end main function
```

Comment: Surely `scanf("%f", &array[num])`should be `scanf("%f", &array[x])`.

Comment: Also, by always using `total` and not `array[x]` when you calculate the tax, you're doing either the vendor or the state (or both) a huge favour. `:)`

Comment: The wall-to-wall comments aren't very helpful: you should leave some space — at least 2 spaces recommended — before tail comments.  By contrast, basic indentation is incredibly helpful.  It shows that the `total = 0;` line is inside a loop and doesn't need to be (you could initialize `total` to zero).  It shows that the grand total is printed for each iteration of the final loop; it doesn't need to be.  You need to calculate and accumulate the tax and total a lot more carefully — you are charging way too much tax if there's more than one item bought.

Comment: You should check each input — and you should probably validate the tax.  If someone types `9%` instead of `0.09` as you expect, or `$35` instead of `35.00` as you expect, then you're going to have major problems.

Comment: I think the problem with your code is you let the user choose how many items they purchase with num. However, you limited your array length to just 10. So if I chose 11, where will my 11th items be stored? Also, for your loop, you always use the num variable as an index value for scanf. That suppose to be x, not num. Otherwise, you just working with that single index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue with your code is just where you scanf() for items. You store value into array[num] and not array[x]. However, there is a lot more than that issue. You let the user choose how many items but you did not enforce the limitation. Also, when you get the total, grand total, and the tax total you ran them in the loop and that mean each loop run you rerun all those calculation again.

To show you those issues, I first show you your code with your problem fix. And then I show you a more optimized method of doing what you wanted to do below that.

Your methods with a few fixes. However still the same calculation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Array Discussion Code
// Sales Tax Calculator
int main() 
{
    const int maxItem = 100;
    //main function initialization
    int x, num; //initialization of integer values
    float array[maxItem] = { 0.0 }, total = 0, tax = 0;//initialization of array, total, and tax floats

    printf("Enter the sales tax rate in your state (in 0.xx format): ");//user is prompted to enter their state sales tax rate
    scanf("%f", &tax);//user enters their sales tax rate
    printf("\nEnter the number of items you purchased(maximum %d): ", maxItem);//prompts the user for the number of items they bought
    scanf("%d", &num);//user inputs the number of products they bought

    while(num > maxItem){
      printf("\nNumber of item purchased can only be at maximum of %d. Please re-enter an amount: ", maxItem);//prompts the user for the number of items they bought
      scanf("%d", &num);//user inputs the number of products they bought
    }

    printf("\nEnter the price of each item: ");//prompts the user to begin entering the prices of each item

    for (x = 0; x<num; x++){//for loop to allow user to input the number of values they want
        printf("\nItem %d: ", x);
        scanf("%f", &array[x]);//user inputs a value
    }
    for (x = 0; x < num; x++){//loop executes as many times as there are items
        total = total + array[x];//for loop to find the total of all items

        printf("\nYour total before tax is $%.2f", total); //program displays total before tax

        tax = tax * total;//total sales tax is calculated

        printf("\nYour sales tax is $%.2f", tax);//total sales tax is displayed

        total = tax + total;//grand total is calculated

        printf("\nYour grand total is $%.2f", total);//grand total is displayed
    }
    return 0;
}//end main function
```

Your methods with calculation fix using an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Array Discussion Code
// Sales Tax Calculator
int main() 
{
    const int maxItem = 100;
    //main function initialization
    int x, num; //initialization of integer values
    float array[maxItem] = { 0.0 }, total = 0, tax = 0;//initialization of array, total, and tax floats

    printf("Enter the sales tax rate in your state (in 0.xx format): ");//user is prompted to enter their state sales tax rate
    scanf("%f", &tax);//user enters their sales tax rate
    printf("\nEnter the number of items you purchased(maximum %d): ", maxItem);//prompts the user for the number of items they bought
    scanf("%d", &num);//user inputs the number of products they bought

    while(num > maxItem){
      printf("\nNumber of item purchased can only be at maximum of %d. Please re-enter an amount: ", maxItem);//prompts the user for the number of items they bought
      scanf("%d", &num);//user inputs the number of products they bought
    }

    printf("\nEnter the price of each item: ");//prompts the user to begin entering the prices of each item

    for (x = 0; x<num; x++){//for loop to allow user to input the number of values they want
        printf("\nItem %d: ", x);
        scanf("%f", &array[x]);//user inputs a value
        total = total + array[x];
    }

    printf("\nYour total before tax is $%.2f", total); //program displays total before tax

    tax = tax * total;//total sales tax is calculated

    printf("\nYour sales tax is $%.2f", tax);//total sales tax is displayed

    total = tax + total;//grand total is calculated

    printf("\nYour grand total is $%.2f", total);//grand total is displayed

    return 0;
}//end main function
```

Your method without using an array and does not limit the number of items.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Array Discussion Code
// Sales Tax Calculator
int main() 
{

    //main function initialization
    int x, num; //initialization of integer values
    float total = 0.0, tax = 0.0, item = 0.0;//initialization of array, total, and tax floats

    printf("Enter the sales tax rate in your state (in 0.xx format): ");//user is prompted to enter their state sales tax rate
    scanf("%f", &tax);//user enters their sales tax rate
    printf("\nEnter the number of items you purchased: ");//prompts the user for the number of items they bought
    scanf("%d", &num);//user inputs the number of products they bought

    printf("\nEnter the price of each item: ");//prompts the user to begin entering the prices of each item

    for (x = 1; x<=num; x++){//for loop to allow user to input the number of values they want
        printf("\nItem %d: ", x);
        scanf("%f", &item);//user inputs a value
        total += item;
    }


    printf("\nYour total before tax is $%.2f", total); //program displays total before tax

    tax = tax * total;//total sales tax is calculated

    printf("\nYour sales tax is $%.2f", tax);//total sales tax is displayed

    total = tax + total;//grand total is calculated

    printf("\nYour grand total is $%.2f", total);//grand total is displayed

    return 0;
}//end main function
```